# iOSでMozcを使いたいがコンパイルエラー

Tags: xcode, objective-c, c

iOS用のMozcベースの日本語変換の方法を探るべく、以下のソースコードをお借りして、実機動作にて検証しようと考えています。
特にMozc日本語変換の方法を取得したいと考えています。
[Japanese Keydord Kit](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/JapaneseKeyboardKit)
[Mozc for iOS](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/Mozc-for-iOS/tree/b47d9e4369352ef7d96277c8b76905fb74b2119a)

しかし、上記のGitHubからお借りしたコードを使おうとすると２つの問題が発生します。
1.実機ではコンパイルエラーになる（後述）
2.シュミレーターでは、コンパイルは通るが実行時に日本語の候補が出てこない。

二番目に関しては、シュミレーターでの動作を保証していないので仕方ないのですが、一番目は下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

[image: エラー表示]

エラー内容から検索し、Bitcodeの設定を変えたり、Linked Frameworks and Librariesを確認したのですが、変化ありません。
おそらくエラーの内容を自分が十分理解できていないことと思います。

他にどのような理由が考えられるか、どのように対処するべきなのか、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Xcode8.3.2
iOS10.3.3

【追記】ご指摘いただきました、手順を追加いたします。

Getting the code

```
$ git clone git@github.com:kishikawakatsumi/JapaneseKeyboardKit.git --recursive
$ cd JapaneseKeyboardKit
```

Build Mozc (Japanese Input Method)

Configure

```
$ cd Mozc-for-iOS/src
$ python build_mozc.py gyp
```

Compilation

```
$ python build_mozc_ios.py
```

Run Sample Project

```
$ cd ../..
$ open JapaneseKeyboardKit.xcodeproj
```

SigningのTeamを設定する。

実機で走らせる。＜ここでエラーが出る＞

Comment: 第三者が問題を再現できるように、簡単でも良いので作業手順を書いて頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

手順の追記のため、一度全て削除してダウンロードからやり直しました。
結果、今回はエラーも出ずに実行できました。

しかし、なぜエラーが出ていたのかは謎ですが、質問項目としては解決しましたので、解決済みとさせていただきます。

手順追加をご提案いただいたことが解決につながりました。
ご提案いただきましたこと、感謝いたします。